# How do I get an instance template to use a snapshot as an additional disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'd like to set up an instance template to create a new disk based off of an existing snapshot. When I configure the instance template in the web console it appears to allow this (see image below) but when I attempt to create a VM from the instance template the drive shows up as "New Drive". I notice that this is not an issue if the new drive is created from an image (also included in the image below). How can I get an instance template to use a snapshot to create a new drive?

**Creating the instance template allows me to create a new drive with a snapshot "geoserver-data-disk-snapshot":**

[image: Creating the instance template allows me to create a new drive with a snapshot "geoserver-data-disk-snapshot"]

**However, creating a VM from the instance template only creates a "Blank" disk from the one that was configured from the "geoserver-data-disk-snapshot" snapshot:**

[image: However, creating a VM from the instance template only creates a "Blank" disk from the one that was configured from the "geoserver-data-disk-snapshot" snapshot.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looked at the `gcloud` command line proposed by the Cloud Console when you create a VM instance from an instance template, you would see that instead of a command with an expected option `--source-instance-template` it composes a plain command `gcloud compute instances create` that disregards the source snapshot setting:

```
$ gcloud beta compute --project=my-project instances create vm-from-instance-template \
--create-disk=mode=rw,auto-delete=yes,size=10,type=pd-standard,device-name=persistent-disk-1 
...
```

The `gcloud` command

```
$ gcloud compute instances create vm-gcloud-from-instance-template-1 \
--source-instance-template instance-template-1 \
...
```

behaves in a similar way: it creates a VM instance with a blank additional disk instead of a disk from a snapshot.

The documentation [Creating a VM instance from an instance template with overrides](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-instance-template#creating_a_vm_instance_from_an_instance_template_with_overrides) claims

> When you use an instance template to start a VM instance, the default
>   behavior is to create a VM instance **exactly as described in the
>   instance template** with the exception of the instance name and zone.

In fact, the source snapshot setting for an additional disk is disregarded.

To overcome this, you should specify the source snapshot explicitly:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create vm-from-instance-template \
--source-instance-template instance-template-1 \
--create-disk=mode=rw,auto-delete=yes,size=10,source-snapshot=snapshot-1 \
...
```

[Developer Tools > Cloud SDK: Command Line Interface > Doc > Reference > gcloud compute instances create > --create-disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--create-disk)

Comment: Thank you! Just to be clear, are you saying "creating a template with a disk from a snapshot in the google cloud is broken"? This is important when using this template to make an instance group for load balancing. It means the template needs to make its own disk manually through the startup script or some other method since there's no human there to invoke the `gcloud compute instances create ...` command.

Comment: Yes, this thing does not work as described in the documentation. But even if it worked, it would not bring you benefits, because instance templates are immutable (this is crucial for keeping group members identical during autoscaling and autohealing), whereas scheduled snapshots have unique autogenerated names.

Comment: To keep up with the moving point-in-time you'd need to create a new template for each new snapshot, and then, when needed, to create a new instance group based on that template. Each instance in that new instance group would work with its own replica of the same snapshot. That means that disks created from the snapshot should be read-only to keep data consistent while serving the load-balanced requests. This functionality is not provided in GCP. This should be scripted.